# Conditional count from multiple table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 4 tables: `Tenant`, `Tenant_Vendor_Relationship`, `Tenant_Sell`, `Vendor_Sell`

Type in tenant table shows whether its a vendor or tenant.

I want to write a query which will return count based on following conditions input to query is `tid` (tenant Id):

1. If: `tid` is present in `Tenant_Vendor_Relationship` follow below steps otherwise return 0.
2. If type of tenant is `tenant` then return count from `Tenant_Sell`.
3. If type of tenant is `vendor` and at least one row for column `tenant_initiator` in `Tenant_Vendor_Relationship` for that: `tid` is `Y` then return count from `Tenant_Sell`, else from `Vendor_Sell` with `vid=:tid`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Tenant(tid int, name varchar(50), type varchar(50))
CREATE TABLE Tenant_Vendor_Relationship(relid int, tid int, vid int,
    tenant_initiator varchar(50))
CREATE TABLE Tenant_Sell(sid int, tid int)
CREATE TABLE Vendor_Sell(sid int, vid int)
INSERT INTO Tenant (tid, name, type)
VALUES (1, 'SSK','tenant'),
       (2, 'PK group','tenant'),
       (3,'JD','tenant'),
       (4, 'JP Morgan','vendor'),
       (5, 'Toyota','vendor'),
       (6,'SAMSUNG','vendor');

INSERT INTO Tenant_Vendor_Relationship(relid , tid , vid ,tenant_initiator)
VALUES (1, 1, 4,'Y'),
       (2, 1, 5,'N'),
       (3, 2, 4,'Y'),
       (4, 4, 5,'Y'),
       (5, 6, 5,'N');
        
INSERT INTO Tenant_Sell(sid, tid)
VALUES (1, 1),
       (2, 1),
       (3, 1),
       (4, 2),
       (5, 3);

INSERT INTO Vendor_Sell(sid, vid)
VALUES (1, 4),
       (2, 6),
       (3, 5),
       (4, 4),
       (5, 5);
```

Example:

1. For input `tid = 1`, as the type is `tenant` in tenant table and two relationship exists in `Tenant_Vendor_Relationship`, so it should return count from `Tenant_Sell`. That is `3`.
2. For input `tid = 4`, as the type is `vendor` in tenant table and one relationship exists in `Tenant_Vendor_Relationship` and `tenant_initiator` is `Y`, so it should return count from `Tenant_Sell`. That is `0`.
3. For input `tid = 5`, as the type is `vendor` in tenant table and zero relationship exists in `Tenant_Vendor_Relationship`, so it should return count `0`.
4. For input `tid = 6`, as the type is `vendor` in tenant table and one relationship exists in `Tenant_Vendor_Relationship` and `tenant_initiator` is `N`  so it should return count from `Vendor_Sell` where `vid=:tid`. That will return `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join `Tenant_Vendor_Relationship` to `Tenant` with an `INNER` join and then to the other 2 tables with `LEFT` joins:

```
SELECT COUNT(COALESCE(ts.tid, vs.vid)) counter
FROM Tenant_Vendor_Relationship tvr
INNER JOIN Tenant t ON t.tid = tvr.tid
LEFT JOIN Tenant_Sell ts ON ts.tid = tvr.tid AND tvr.tenant_initiator = 'Y'
LEFT JOIN Vendor_Sell vs ON vs.vid = tvr.tid AND tvr.tenant_initiator = 'N' AND t.type = 'vendor'
WHERE tvr.tid = ?
```

You need `Vendor_Sell` only for the case that all `tenant_initiator`s are `'N'` and `type` is `'vendor'`.
Change `?` to the `tid` that you search for.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e2af56379915985acbf83d8f6163f53d).

Answer (score 2):

```sql
CREATE TABLE Tenant(tid int, name varchar(50), TYPE varchar(50))
CREATE TABLE Tenant_Vendor_Relationship
    (relid int, tid int, vid int, tenant_initiator varchar(50))
CREATE TABLE Tenant_Sell(sid int, tid int)
CREATE TABLE Vendor_Sell(sid int, vid int)
INSERT INTO Tenant (tid, name, TYPE)
VALUES (1, 'SSK','tenant'),
       (2, 'PK group','tenant'),
       (3,'JD','tenant'),
       (4, 'JP Morgan','vendor'),
       (5, 'Toyota','vendor'),
       (6,'SAMSUNG','vendor');

INSERT INTO Tenant_Vendor_Relationship(relid, tid, vid, tenant_initiator)
VALUES (1, 1,4,'Y'),
       (2, 1,5,'N'),
       (3,2,4,'Y'),
       (4,4,5,'Y'),
       (5,6,5,'N');

INSERT INTO Tenant_Sell(sid, tid)
VALUES (1, 1),
       (2, 1),
       (3,1),
       (4,2),
       (5,3);

INSERT INTO Vendor_Sell(sid, vid)
VALUES (1, 4),
       (2, 6),
       (3,5),
       (4,4),
       (5,5);

SELECT DISTINCT t.tid, 
CASE
    WHEN  t.tenant_initiator = '' THEN 0
    WHEN t.type = 'tenant' THEN  t.tcount
    WHEN t.type = 'vendor' AND t.tenant_initiator = 'Y' THEN  t.tcount 
    WHEN t.type = 'vendor' AND t.tenant_initiator = 'N' THEN  t.vcount 
    ELSE -1 END 
FROM (
    SELECT n.tid, n.type, ISNULL(r.tenant_initiator, '') AS tenant_initiator,
        ISNULL(a.tcount, 0) AS tcount, ISNULL(b.vcount, 0) AS vcount
    FROM Tenant n
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT tid, tenant_initiator
        FROM Tenant_Vendor_Relationship WHERE tenant_initiator = 'Y'
        UNION
        SELECT tid, tenant_initiator FROM Tenant_Vendor_Relationship
        WHERE tid NOT IN (
            SELECT tid FROM Tenant_Vendor_Relationship
            WHERE tenant_initiator = 'Y'
        )
    ) r ON r.tid = n.tid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT tid, COUNT(*) AS tcount FROM Tenant_Sell
    GROUP BY tid) a ON a.tid = n.tid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT vid, COUNT(*) AS vcount FROM Vendor_Sell
    GROUP BY vid) b ON b.vid = n.tid
) t
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/990322/25

Comment: Its giving wrong answer for tid =6 for below the answer should be 3 
 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/990322/1/0    Its actually failing condition number 3. That is if atleast one 'Y' in Tenant_Vendor_Relationship  then It should return from Tenant_Sell if all are 'N' then only from Vendor_Sell.

Comment: Thank you its providing expected output. Is there any way that we can optimize the query with single left outer join as we are reading only tcount or vcount.